# Build is Crashing on Start

Tags: c#, macos, crash, unity-game-engine

How can I get to the bottom of what's going on in this crash report? Is there something specific that might point to what I might have done wrong? It runs fine in Unity when I play it. Where might be a good place to start debugging things?

```
Process:               RollBallRoll [3441]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/RollBallRoll.app/Contents/MacOS/RollBallRoll
Identifier:            unity.DefaultCompany.RollBallRoll
Version:               Unity Player version 5.1.3f1 (5.1.3f1)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           RollBallRoll [3441]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-09-21 13:45:36.439 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        C2286B65-7F88-7C2F-3532-0F6020730C33


Time Awake Since Boot: 1900 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _mono_set_dirs
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/RollBallRoll.app/Contents/MacOS/RollBallRoll
  Expected in: /Users/USER/Desktop/RollBallRoll.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libmono.0.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   dyld                            0x8fea8085 dyld_fatal_error + 1
1   dyld                            0x8feab175 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 184
2   libdyld.dylib                   0x919ab46c dyld_stub_binder_ + 20
3   unity.DefaultCompany.RollBallRoll   0x009dcaf1 0x1000 + 10337009
4   unity.DefaultCompany.RollBallRoll   0x00e622f3 0x1000 + 15078131
5   unity.DefaultCompany.RollBallRoll   0x00e63c2d 0x1000 + 15084589
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x97f880f3 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 50
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x91addc34 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x919bd901 _CFXNotificationPost + 3713
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x97f692c4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fcf868 -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 365
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fcf558 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 239
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fcc05d -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 827
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fcb92a -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 277
14  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9bd55119 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x97f9fe57 __76-[NSAppleEventManager setEventHandler:andSelector:forEventClass:andEventID:]_block_invoke + 118
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x97f9f99f -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 451
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x97f9f794 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 211
18  com.apple.AE                    0x9bac294e aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned long, unsigned char*) + 583
19  com.apple.AE                    0x9ba8d467 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 44
20  com.apple.AE                    0x9ba8d35a aeProcessAppleEvent + 313
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9064e1c1 AEProcessAppleEvent + 55
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fc52ee _DPSNextEvent + 2707
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fc41e5 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 350
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x94fb8b9c -[NSApplication run] + 907
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x94f2dfa0 NSApplicationMain + 2082
26  unity.DefaultCompany.RollBallRoll   0x00e62ef3 0x1000 + 15081203
27  unity.DefaultCompany.RollBallRoll   0x00002c55 0x1000 + 7253

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c38ce kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x9870673f _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 245
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x987063a2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c2e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a45372a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a450e0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c2e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a45372a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a450e0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c2e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a45372a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a450e0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c2e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a45372a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a450e0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c2e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a45372a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a450e0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c2e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a45372a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a450e0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c2e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a45372a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a450e0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924c2e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a45372a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9a450e0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x8fedc52c  ebx: 0x919ab3cd  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x8ff044c0
  edi: 0x8ff044c0  esi: 0x8feaafd4  ebp: 0xbfffe9e8  esp: 0xbfffe9cc
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000246  eip: 0x8fea8085   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x07fff000

Logical CPU:     4
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3


Binary Images:
    0x1000 -  0x109ffaf +unity.DefaultCompany.RollBallRoll (Unity Player version 5.1.3f1 - 5.1.3f1) <1DB634E3-1321-30DD-B6A4-95B310C63B13> /Users/USER/Desktop/RollBallRoll.app/Contents/MacOS/RollBallRoll
 0x1202000 -  0x147bff9 +libmono.0.dylib (1) <3208E9EE-59C6-38E4-9AAC-BF6461D326D1> /Users/USER/Desktop/RollBallRoll.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx/libmono.0.dylib
 0x7ec5000 -  0x7f12ff7  com.apple.CloudDocs (1.0 - 321.10) <9343D667-13D3-379C-BDCA-7D6D6B8CC7E5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/CloudDocs
 0x7ff6000 -  0x7ff6ff9 +cl_kernels (???) <59563CDB-4BA6-4538-9D63-75EA0BAEA71D> cl_kernels
 0x7ffc000 -  0x7ffcffb +cl_kernels (???) <1D8896BC-5A91-412C-91ED-64B70CC947AA> cl_kernels
 0xc800000 -  0xc8ebff7  unorm8_bgra.dylib (2.4.5) <AD3F3B00-6204-39CD-8085-9BE262AF8A77> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_bgra.dylib
0x8fea7000 - 0x8fedadd3  dyld (353.2.3) <2DB428B9-7749-3455-B87D-323F61131929> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90008000 - 0x9000cff3  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <EE0D6865-A6E0-3BF0-93F1-837C09AA7978> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
0x9000d000 - 0x9002afff  libCRFSuite.dylib (34) <781A92EF-410E-39B2-953D-FEE12748D834> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x9002b000 - 0x900a8ff3  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1050.20.2) <84299E45-C5F3-365F-AC1B-0EAFF8057112> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x900a9000 - 0x900b0fff  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (5.0.9 - 5.0.9) <5D268178-3812-3777-92A6-D7D3395405B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x900b1000 - 0x900bafff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.6 - 2.6) <D906604A-1D8C-31BF-8F22-EA219FFC858F> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x900bb000 - 0x90158fff  com.apple.ink.framework (10.9 - 213) <F47949BC-ABEE-329B-B568-71C6FEF761F6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x90159000 - 0x901c4ff7  com.apple.framework.CoreWiFi (3.0 - 300.4) <632A811D-4706-3ED7-85E3-DD2CDB47CF8F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreWiFi.framework/Versions/A/CoreWiFi
0x901c5000 - 0x901c7fff  com.apple.securityhi (9.0 - 55006) <A0A1E528-E3FA-34D2-AD3B-5C4DF2FE438E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
0x901c8000 - 0x901cbfff  libpam.2.dylib (20) <E2F34522-448A-3392-BC1D-6625BEB612B9> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
0x901cc000 - 0x901ceffb  libsystem_secinit.dylib (18) <3CBA3BD3-8BA2-358D-BD1A-A1C3DF5D84E6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
0x901cf000 - 0x901dfff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <DBECFAD5-DB53-390C-AE92-09549733C861> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x901e0000 - 0x901e0fff  liblaunch.dylib (559.40.1) <65101C3E-CC60-3528-A306-991309171B8A> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x901f7000 - 0x90407fff  com.apple.CFNetwork (720.5.7 - 720.5.7) <8CE218EB-78CD-3757-B185-8FA6CB56F5B5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x90408000 - 0x904f9ffb  libiconv.2.dylib (42) <4AF77F10-0BEC-3BE0-99DF-C5170EDB316B> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x904fa000 - 0x90610ff3  com.apple.desktopservices (1.9.3 - 1.9.3) <544FDA55-063A-3787-A55A-A54290E4BE6E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x90611000 - 0x909eaff3  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 758.7) <6BC046E4-02B6-3E08-8565-77E39E4654B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x909eb000 - 0x90a40ff3  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.3.0 - 4.3.0) <2AF304F7-5DA4-3035-9E15-070F16700789> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x90a41000 - 0x90a63ff3  libssl.0.9.7.dylib (106) <E0174C8B-F4E3-3B8C-9F88-1D7B088DC155> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
0x90a64000 - 0x90a66fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.20.5) <8F74D383-C8B0-32DD-89C1-1E99034AF763> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x90a67000 - 0x90ac0ff3  libAVFAudio.dylib (118.6) <D91F498D-AF1E-368B-9DCB-CDA3AAA0E6CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x90ac1000 - 0x90ac1fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.10 - Accelerate 1.10) <C2367B5B-AE20-3084-A864-104743BE478E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x90ac2000 - 0x90ac2fff  libunc.dylib (29) <CE960997-9D4A-3848-BAC7-B2255E6765FD> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
0x90af1000 - 0x90af1fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.8 - 21) <6AF80DDB-C28E-36FF-BC11-D7D561AC52A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
0x90af2000 - 0x90b18ff3  libxpc.dylib (559.40.1) <D765980C-9448-3637-AE66-360C7DC2DCEB> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x90b19000 - 0x90b19fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.10 - vecLib 3.10) <F968D12F-F59D-3148-951D-76735C3C1B57> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x90b1a000 - 0x90b39ffb  libresolv.9.dylib (57) <C2C3810A-A45E-3375-B41D-6E1BECE1BA3C> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x90b3a000 - 0x90b54ff7  liblzma.5.dylib (7) <D0BC984D-5B33-328C-8F1E-7E9C41813433> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x90b59000 - 0x90c0bfff  libCoreStorage.dylib (471.30.1) <8AB3BEEF-AB8E-310F-B066-8E482958B57A> /usr/lib/libCoreStorage.dylib
0x90c0c000 - 0x90c35fff  libsystem_info.dylib (459.40.1) <4827C088-2BF0-397F-B9FA-0F91BDF64637> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x90c36000 - 0x90c42ff7  libkxld.dylib (2782.40.9) <C98D6387-DEDE-344C-9C25-4B3FC5033001> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x90ec9000 - 0x90f24ffb  libTIFF.dylib (1239) <FFA7D348-7839-3AAC-B0DC-BEAD5E1433AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
0x90f25000 - 0x90f57ffb  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <2B5A899E-055E-3BEC-A8A1-F8570983389B> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
0x90f58000 - 0x90f6ffff  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) <85BD88AD-618E-3325-AC31-10DBAB8E9AF3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x90f70000 - 0x90faafff  com.apple.LDAPFramework (2.4.28 - 194.5) <E3E6B657-AA4C-3D9D-8EB2-ACAC1B62DDDE> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
0x90fab000 - 0x913a6ffb  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 788.3) <96ECAEE8-9FCA-33C5-8DBF-832C7B3C1CA5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0x913a7000 - 0x913b4ff3  com.apple.ProtocolBuffer (1 - 228.0.1) <B61B9562-CBDE-34E5-B19E-291A1D95D782> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/Versions/A/ProtocolBuffer
0x913b5000 - 0x913ccffb  com.apple.AppContainer (4.0 - 238.20.2) <0A9A3DD3-2D64-3548-8374-96FCE828D151> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppContainer.framework/Versions/A/AppContainer
0x913cd000 - 0x913cefff  liblangid.dylib (117) <34A0F807-755F-300B-B01F-AABAE3838451> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x913cf000 - 0x915c5fff  libicucore.A.dylib (531.48) <A1002DA8-DAA9-30E8-95AE-1BF575AC5AB5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x915c6000 - 0x91757ff3  libsqlite3.dylib (168.2) <85773EDA-5470-326B-8C21-20A80C89C96A> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x91758000 - 0x9175dfff  com.apple.print.framework.Print (10.0 - 265) <7C3984BB-8337-3B90-A414-17C181A45744> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
0x917cf000 - 0x91809fff  com.apple.AirPlaySupport (2.0 - 215.18) <80A5662C-D50C-3FCF-8636-AA60725B516C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/Versions/A/AirPlaySupport
0x91899000 - 0x918a2ffb  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0) <CEB9667F-4511-36E5-82EC-95CC1C48AC3B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth
0x918a3000 - 0x918b0ff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib (36) <6BC7B049-8F03-3217-9840-B1804CCBF742> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x918b1000 - 0x91957fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 917.36) <6B6C3094-6820-3621-BC4D-3BECECEC5918> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x91958000 - 0x919a9fff  com.apple.opencl (2.4.2 - 2.4.2) <B9796163-3EC0-3FAD-B4E1-F83EA2A2DD94> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x919aa000 - 0x919adfff  libdyld.dylib (353.2.3) <9E52D315-C3CD-30B6-AA06-50B529D9AC38> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x919ae000 - 0x91d62ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1153.18) <267B1002-C755-37B4-95CD-92358CF994B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x91d63000 - 0x91d69ff3  libsystem_platform.dylib (63) <509993B7-3F26-3360-B899-0BBB15152516> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x91d6a000 - 0x91e35fff  com.apple.backup.framework (1.6.5 - 1.6.5) <F2F66289-39DD-3033-A56B-DC8A9495C782> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
0x91e36000 - 0x91f01fff  com.apple.DiscRecording (9.0 - 9000.4.2) <8E19F180-3D32-3C7A-8E73-272F2955D9A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecording.framework/Versions/A/DiscRecording
0x91f02000 - 0x91f76fff  com.apple.Heimdal (4.0 - 2.0) <DA206336-378C-3F65-9606-466BC3FDD824> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
0x91f77000 - 0x920bbff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1239) <EED27F3A-C2AF-3555-93BF-83A37AAE1D42> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x920bc000 - 0x920bdfff  libremovefile.dylib (35) <49DCAF7B-4466-3775-9E58-EA5D7CBA8AE0> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x920be000 - 0x92107ffb  libFontRegistry.dylib (134.1) <6CF6177B-D5D6-3E7B-88BC-BE833D55018C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
0x92108000 - 0x9212eff7  com.apple.IconServices (47.1 - 47.1) <9C537499-B375-3F84-BF4A-EEF757FC26A9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IconServices.framework/Versions/A/IconServices
0x9212f000 - 0x922f4fff  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.10 - 361.19) <1E3BC4E7-7008-3802-A563-FBAB6726E332> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x922f5000 - 0x922f7ffb  libCGXType.A.dylib (788.3) <E069924C-6DF5-3B50-86A3-4A382E0150AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x922f8000 - 0x922fcffb  libGIF.dylib (1239) <FE1E5A53-4B05-387B-942E-3B6C3175A275> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x922fd000 - 0x92330fff  com.apple.CoreAVCHD (5.7.5 - 5750.4.1) <103A5EA0-9B75-3B23-BE72-C4DD52744A6A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAVCHD.framework/Versions/A/CoreAVCHD
0x92331000 - 0x92364fe3  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <951F633F-57B7-398B-912F-F6ED4DB1C597> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x92365000 - 0x92478fff  com.apple.MediaControlSender (2.0 - 215.18) <A457A15F-942E-3BCC-B114-FF0C0735B52D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/Versions/A/MediaControlSender...
```

Comment: After googling `Symbol not found: _mono_set_dirs`, some forum posts refer to the same problem, which was resolved by setting the architecture type to x64. (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/4-6-1p1-any-osx-build-crashes-immediately-on-startup-edit-also-on-4-6-1p2.285296/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361498/mkbundle-failed-to-compile-c-sharp-application-on-os-x)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Switching to x64 resolved the crashing issue.